# Terraform using wrong version of provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a Postgres server on Azure using the `azurerm_postgresql_server` resource block. I've got the `azurerm` version pinned to 2.4.0 which means I should be up to date and can use the examples from the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/postgresql_server.html). Instead, I'm getting missing required argument errors and seeing messages refer to missing attributes, that according to the documentation are deprecated.

So far I've tried running `terraform init -upgrade` in case I had previously tried a Postgres creation with an older version of the provider and it caused a cached version of the plugin but it's not had any effect. I have no idea what's wrong - if it's the code itself or the terraform setup on my machine. Simplified code snippet and error output are below, thanks!

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version           = "=2.4.0"
  subscription_id   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  features {
    key_vault {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy = true
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "postgres" {
  name                         = "sarum-hymnal-postgresql-server"
  location                     = var.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group.name
  sku_name                     = "B_Gen4_1"
  storage_mb                   = 5120
  backup_retention_days        = 7
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled = false
  auto_grow_enabled            = false
  administrator_login          = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.POSTGRES-USERNAME.value
  administrator_login_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.POSTGRES-SECRET.value
  version                      = "11"
  ssl_enforcement_enabled      = true
  tags                         = var.resource_group.tags
}
```

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on sarum-hymnal/main.tf line 26, in resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "postgres":
  26: resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "postgres" {

The argument "ssl_enforcement" is required, but no definition was found.


Error: Unsupported argument

  on sarum-hymnal/main.tf line 31, in resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "postgres":
  31:   storage_mb                   = 5120

An argument named "storage_mb" is not expected here.
```

by running `terraform providers` at the root directory I get the following output:

```
 .
 ├── provider.azurerm =2.4.0
 ├── module.early-modern-ballot
 │   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
 ├── module.hands-on-reading
 │   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
 ├── module.poetic-transformations
 │   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
 ├── module.sarum-hymnal
 │   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
 ├── module.soundscapes-of-text
 │   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
 └── module.translations
     └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
```

Comment: Can you show the version of the `azurerm` provider in the root config directory?

Comment: by running `terraform providers` at the root directory I get the following output: ```.
├── provider.azurerm =2.4.0
├── module.early-modern-ballot
│   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
├── module.hands-on-reading
│   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
├── module.poetic-transformations
│   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
├── module.sarum-hymnal
│   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
├── module.soundscapes-of-text
│   └── provider.azurerm (inherited)
└── module.translations
    └── provider.azurerm (inherited)```

Comment: What is output of `terraform version`?

Comment: terraform version is 0.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could upgrade your terraform version to `v0.12` and the version of the `azurerm` provider to `version = ">=2.7"`. This works on my side.

[image]

See [v2.0 of the AzureRM Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/2.0-upgrade-guide.html) and [Upgrading to Terraform v0.12](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html) for more details.

Comment: Bumping the provider version up to 2.7 fixed the issue